# Interactive d3 zip code choropleth - WA state

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson, choropleth

As the title says, I'm trying to make an interactive choropleth using d3. I've found an interesting example that I'm trying to replicate for another location.
Concretely, I'm trying to plot the Washington state, at the zip code level.

I've added the [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/TtYvAE6ISkhxTSdlNlR3) I have at the moment that could be potentially edited, it's based on this [example](https://github.com/martinbel/d3_zip_choropleth) here is the live [demo](http://controlaltdelete.io/d3-zip-code-choropleth/) that shows the final result.

This is working for the California state, however when changing the zip code topojson state (to Washington state) the plot doesn't work. Also there are no explicit errors. The error could be in differences in the topojson.

This is the [california topojson](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinbel/d3_zip_choropleth/master/data/zip_code_crs84.topojson), here the [Washington version](https://gist.github.com/martinbel/e14cd6ecd565914f53af).

Below are the first values pretty printed for each topojson.

```
California topojson:
    {
      "type": "Topology",
      "objects": {
        "zip": {
          "type": "GeometryCollection",
          "crs": {
            "type": "name",
            "properties": {
              "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
            }
          },
          "geometries": [
            {
              "type": "Polygon",
              "properties": {
                "zipcode": 94601
              },
              "arcs": [
                [
                  0,
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5
                ]
              ]
            }
```

Washington topojson:

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "objects": {
    "tl_2010_53_zcta510": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
          "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
      },
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "properties": {
            "zipcode": "98822"
          },
          "arcs": [
            [
              0,
              1,
              2,
              3
            ],
            [
              4
            ]
          ]
        }
```

The following is the `main.js` function. I assume this and inspecting both topojson files could help find where the problem might be. Basically the only thing changing is the topojson file, then the `main.js` function should reflect these changes.

Also the "fake_data.csv" would just represent a serie of zipcode:value pairs as:

```
zip,values
98001,1
98002,1
98003,1
98004,2
98005,2
98006,2
```

**main.js**

```
    (function chart() {

  var width = 1000,
      height = 1200,
      centered;

  var rateById = d3.map();

  var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
      .domain([0, 100000])
      .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));

  var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
      .scale(6000)
      .translate([2300, 680]);

  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  var svg = d3.select("#ca-chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  var tooltip = d3.select("#ca-chart").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("click", clicked);

  var g = svg.append("g");

// These are the two lines that are different from the working example
  queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/martinbel/e14cd6ecd565914f53af/raw/e3a3a8332c20fe3cee6d7fd2a9ac01ad43f7aaa4/WA.topojson")
      .defer(d3.csv, "fake_data.csv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.zip.toString(), +d.values); })
      .await(ready);

  function ready(error, zipcode) {
    var features = topojson.feature(zipcode, zipcode.objects.tl_2010_53_zcta510).features;

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "state")
      .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(zipcode, zipcode.objects.tl_2010_53_zcta510).features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("stroke", "#333")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
        .attr("fill", "#fff");

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "zipcodes")
      .selectAll("path")
        .data(features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", getColorClass)
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("click", clicked)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout);
  }

  function getColorClass(d) {
    return quantize(rateById.get(d.properties.zipcode));
  }

  function getPopulation(d) {
    return rateById.get(getZip(d)).toString();
  }

  function getZip(d) {
    return d && d.properties ? d.properties.zipcode : null;
  }

  function mouseout(d) {
    d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke", null);

    tooltip.transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("opacity", 0);
  }

  function mouseover(d) {
    d3.select(this.parentNode.appendChild(this))
        .style("stroke", "#F00");

    tooltip.transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("opacity", 1);

    tooltip
        .html("<p><strong>Zipcode: " + getZip(d) + "<br>Population: "  + getPopulation(d) + "</strong></p>")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 25) + "px")
        .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    }

  function clicked(d) {
    var x, y, k;

    if (d && centered !== d) {
      var centroid = path.centroid(d);
      x = centroid[0];
      y = centroid[1];
      k = 8;    // control zoom depth
      centered = d;
    } else {
      x = width / 2;
      y = height / 2;
      k = 1;
      centered = null;
    }

    g.selectAll("path")
        .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

    g.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
  }

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

}());
```

#### The topojson file was produced in the following way:

```
curl -O "ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/ZCTA5/2010/tl_2010_53_zcta510.zip"
unzip "tl_2010_53_zcta510.zip"
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs crs:84 -t_srs crs:84 tl_2010_53_zcta510.geojson tl_2010_53_zcta510.shp
topojson -o tl_2010_53_zcta510.topojson --properties zipcode=ZCTA5CE10 tl_2010_53_zcta510.geojson
```

Comment: Marbel, from your question it is not directly clear to me what your problem is. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @tilt I've added more details in the question. Let me know if this helps understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for showing the map and display it without having to hack the parameters by hand. Actually the trick is to use a projection that supports the `.center()` method, `albersUsa` doesn't. Then it's much easier to sort out the scale parameter.

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([-120.574951, 47.361153])
            .scale(5000)
            .translate([(width) / 2, (height)/2]);
```

After this some other issues appeared.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're drawing the paths outside of the active viewing area. Try just this as your `projection` and you'll see the paths.

```
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
  // .scale(6000)
  // .translate([2300, 680]);
```

You'll have to edit the scaling/translation for Washington...might be helpful to make your svg `width` and `height` ginormous (10000px or so) as you do this just so you can see where the map ends up.

Comment: Isn't there a better way of doing this? Ideally I wouldn't want to change parameters manually.